# The canonical base point for Weil algebras

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, synthetic-differential-geometry

[Kock](http://home.math.au.dk/kock/sdg99.pdf) defines, after (16.2), the canonical base point of a small object $\operatorname{Spec}_R(W)$ to be $$\mathbf 1\overset{\operatorname{Spec}_R (\pi)}{\longrightarrow}\operatorname{Spec}_RW$$where $\pi:W\rightarrow R$ is the augmentation map of the Weil algebra $W$, and the $\mathbf 1$ is just $\operatorname{Spec}_RR$. Thing is, I don't understand what $\operatorname{Spec}_R$ does to arrows as a functor, since there are no prime ideals to take inverse images of.

So, what does $\operatorname{Spec}_R$ do as a functor, and how does it follow that in the case of the dual numbers, it chooses zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Lavendhomme's *Basic Concepts of Synthetic Differential Geometry*, chapter 2, section 2.1.1, after definition 1.

Given $f:W_1\rightarrow W_2$, choose finite presentations and define $\operatorname{Spec}_R(f)(b_1,\dots ,b_{r^\prime})=(a_1,\dots ,a_r)$ by $a_i=f(x_i)(b_1,\dots ,b_{r^\prime})$.